# Role based authorization: Oauth with OneLogin and Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, onelogin

I have a spring boot application which is using Oauth with OneLogin as the authorisation server.
Now, I want to implement role based authorisation to expose certain APIs only to users with certain privileges.

I have users belonging to groups. Say user A belongs to "admin" group and user B does not belong to the admin group. My question is how can I use these groups to enable only user A to access certain APIs.

This is the information about the authenticated user for reference:

```
authorities 
0   
authority   "ROLE_USER"           **//says ROLE_USER even when the user belongs to the admin group** 
attributes  
at_hash "xxxxx"
sub "xxxx"
iss "https://******/oidc/2"
groups  
0   "Group A"
1   "Group B"
2   **"DEMO"**
3   **"DEMO Admin"**               **//presence in this group should be considered for authorisation**
preferred_username  "xxx"
given_name  "xxxx"
nonce   "xxxxxxx"
sid "xxxxxxx"
aud 
0   "xxxxxxx"
updated_at  "xxxxxx"
name    "xxxxxx"
exp "xxxxxxx"
family_name "xxxxxx"
iat "xxxxxxxx"
email   "xxxxxxxx"
idToken {…}
userInfo    {…}
1   
authority   "SCOPE_email"
2   
authority   "SCOPE_groups"
3   
authority   "SCOPE_openid"
4   
authority   "SCOPE_profile"
```

I want to secure my rest controllers something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("Belongs to group admin")
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public string delete() {
  System.out.println("delete");
}
```

This is my application.yaml file

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /demo


spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          onelogin:
            client-id: *****
            client-secret: *******
            scope: openid,profile,email,groups
            provider: onelogin
        provider:
          onelogin:
            issuer-uri: https://******/oidc/2
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that your application is both an OAuth2 client and resource server?

Comment: Yes. That is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application is also a resource server, you can use a custom `JwtAuthenticationConverter` to configure how the JWT gets converted to an `Authentication` object. Specifically for this case, you can configure how the JWT gets converted to the list of `GrantedAuthorities`.

By default, the resource server populates the `GrantedAuthorities` based on the `"scope"` claim.
If the JWT contains a claim with the name `"scope"` or `"scp"`, then Spring Security will use the value in that claim to construct the authorities by prefixing each value with `"SCOPE_"`. That is why you see the authorities "SCOPE_email", "SCOPE_groups" etc

If you want to populate the `GrantedAuthorities` based on the "groups" claim instead, you can do so like this:

```java
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
    return converter;
}

public class CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String group : getGroups(jwt)) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(group));
        }
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}

private Collection<String> getGroups(Jwt jwt) {
    Object groups = jwt.getClaim("groups");
    // Convert groups to Collection of Strings based on your logic
}
```

Then you can use the expression `"hasAuthority('YOUR_CUSTOM_GROUP_NAME')"` to restrict access to certain endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I get the following error when I add your converter code. 
Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that could not be found.

Comment: You will need to set the `issuer-uri` in the resource server as well. The YML is very similar to what you have currently. Take a look at this section in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#specifying-the-authorization-server