# Users' authorities/roles are not being considered when accessing a route through Zuul Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, netflix-zuul

I set up the permissions to a URL in the Zuul Gateway microservice because I access the endpoints through the gateway, so I believe there is where I should put the rules.

The client, token, roles, and authorities are all stored in the database.

**`roles`**

[image]

**`authorities`**

[image]

An `ADMIN` can read and write, while `USER` can only read. I generate a token user my admin credentials at `oauth/token`, then upon checking it at `oauth/check_token`, the following:

```
GET http://localhost:8765/authorization-service/oauth/check_token?token=f23e9fcc-1a85-43c4-8ef2-4efd00a7ccf5

{
    "active": true,
    "exp": 1604879905,
    "user_name": "gamofe",
    "authorities": [
        "ROLE_ADMIN",
        "CAN_MANAGE",
        "CAN_READ"
    ],
    "client_id": "client",
    "scope": [
        "READ",
        "WRITE"
    ]
}
```

In the Zuul gateway microservice, I created a `@Configuration` class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to apply the rules to the routes. In here, I set up to permit all access to `authorization-service/**` and at `/user-service/api/v1/users/**` to have any role `ADMIN` or `USER`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public static final String USERS_URI = "/user-service/api/v1/users/**";
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authorization-service/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(USERS_URI).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken();
    }
}
```

I also set the instrospection-uri in application.yml file:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        opaquetoken:
          introspection-uri: 'http://localhost:8765/authorization-service/oauth/check_token'
          client-id: 'client'
          client-secret: 'pass'
```

And while `.anyRequest().authenticated().and()` effectively checks if a user is indeed authenticated, its authorities and roles are ignored, always forbidding access to a protected route.

```
$ curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8765/user-service/api/v1/users' --header 'Authorization: Bearer f23e9fcc-1a85-43c4-8ef2-4efd00a7ccf5'
{"timestamp":"2020-11-08T23:26:21.012+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/user-service/api/v1/users"}%
```

I tried with `hasAuthority`, I tried modifying the endpoint in many ways, I don't know what's missing. If I remove the `hasAnyRole` line it will allow me again, it seems it's not able to see the authorities the user has.

I don't know what else to add, so please ask me. Or if you're feeling kind enough, you can [check my repository.](https://github.com/mfgabriel92/spring-microservices)

Comment: I can't see anywhere where your application is validating the incoming token. How does it know how to extract the roles from the token? Did you mean to make your application a resource server?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Hum, maybe that's what's missing, I didn't do anything of the sort on Zuul gateway but applying the rules to the routes. I don't know either if that'd mean to make the gateway a resource server.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana hi, can you still help?

Comment: If you want the gateway to validate the token and extract the roles then you will have to make it a resource server. Alternatively, you can move the authorization rule (`hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")`) to the user-service and make that one into a resource server. You will need to make one of the applications into a resource server, if you want to use OAuth 2.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, alright, I get it. I will try and eventually reply back here. Thank you.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, hi. So I tried implementing token introspection-uri and it seems it solved 50%. I say 50% because `.anyRequest().authenticated()` works now, while before it wouldn't. But despite that, it still doesn't read the authorities of a user and I can't find anything simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: The authorities are being populated based on the "scope" claim. Take a look at this answer for how you can change the default https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645351/role-based-authorization-oauth-with-onelogin-and-spring-security/64678541#64678541

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, hi. The scope you mean the scope of the client credentials? I have set one and put "read" and "write" as the scope, and my authorities "can_manage" and "can_read". Is it because of that? Also, I am not using Jwt yet, just OAuth2.